# Format error message on query exception laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I could easily catch laravel query exception as:

```
try{
    //code
}catch(\Exception $e){
  $err = $e->getPrevious()->getMessage();
}
```

This return `$err` as `<pre>SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'column_name' at row 1</pre>`

However, I want the details as mentioned below:

**My requirement:**

1) I want to retrieve column_name. `//column_name`

2) Retrieve the only error message part `//Data truncated for column`

Is there any way that I could get exactly as mentioned above.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can use preg_match to get the data.

```
try{
    //code
}catch(\Exception $e){
   $err = $e->getPrevious()->getMessage();
   $b = preg_match('/(Data truncated for column) \'([a-zA-Z_]+)\'/', $err, $matches);
   if ( $b ) {
       // Found data truncated
       $message = $matches[1];
       $columnName = $matches[2];
   }
}
```

If you want to get just what is between the quotes.

```
$b = preg_match('/\'([a-zA-Z_]+)\'/', $err, $matches);
if ( $b ) {
    $columnName = $matched[1]; // this is what is between the quotes
}
```

Comment: It looks like it works only for data truncated error only. It does not work for other error as `Data too long for column`. Well, leave that aside, how could I retrieve just the column name i.e string between those single quote

Comment: You asked about that specific error so that is what I answered.